# API for completing PayPal one-time payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm looking for ways to make a PayPal payment using PHP. I understand there are deprecated APIs and current one. so I've found several ways to do so. but lots documents lead me into labyrinth. I'm quite confuse de.g. client button rendering, how to call our PHP script/ what is a PayPal-Request-Id and to get it/ what can we do with a token from webscr ==>  cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-7BA65327KY8480517 and etc.

I tried to use a button on my page to submit some few paypal-required parameters using html form. The receiving php file formed payment record as need, then create order. I got the order-id, but what is it for? so I set up a new parameters, conformed the PayPal needs to create a payment. This give me 4 links, one I choose to get redirected for client logging in and continuing. with this one I got to landing page then I executed a payment but each payment on sandbox dashboard says pending.

I am then confused how to get completed payment. Right here there is my data with THB currency

```
{"id":"PAYID-MAKU2OI7RR56034B9692111L","intent":"sale","state":"created","payer":{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":{"total":"1126.15","currency":"THB","details":{"subtotal":"979.26","tax":"146.89","shipping":"0.00","insurance":"0.00","handling_fee":"0.00","shipping_discount":"0.00"}},"description":"aonang to","custom":"0","invoice_number":"kbv.starlight_12","soft_descriptor":"MFWD","payment_options":{"allowed_payment_method":"INSTANT_FUNDING_SOURCE","recurring_flag":false,"skip_fmf":false},"item_list":{"items":[{"name":"MFWD","sku":"kbv.starlight_12","description":"aonang to  ","price":"979.26","currency":"THB","tax":"146.89","quantity":1}]},"related_resources":[]}],"note_to_payer":"Contact us for any questions on your order.","create_time":"2021-01-30T12:12:40Z","links":[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-MAKU2OI7RR56034B9692111L","rel":"self","method":"GET"},{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-1G552540DR9655320","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-MAKU2OI7RR56034B9692111L/execute","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}
```

[Sandbox account interface screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpAZF.jpg)

Comment: var EXECUTE_URL = '/example/executePayment';
 
        /* Set up the data you need to pass to your server */
 
        /* Make a call to your server to execute the payment */
 
        return fetch('/my-server/capture-paypal-transaction', {
         body: JSON.stringify({

Answer (score 0):

You mention the classic Express Checkout API and the deprecated v1/payments API, but the right solution is to use the current API, **v2/checkout/orders**

Create two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls).  These routes should return JSON data (and only JSON data) when called by an XHR/fetch.

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: i work follow the given idea, thank you ! now the error becomes paid by unidentified

Comment: If that "unidentified" is in your own system, then yes -- you need to ensure you keep track of who is paying for what.

Comment: I got this ' MFWD2PayPal.php:90 POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/checkout/orders/53S37055166154359/capture 401 (Unauthorized) ' after running php order created 's 3rd links (all are 4) and then the console warns me this "Error: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Comment: i put all detailed required by the client fetch e.g. data header and etc. now, it knows who pays me in sandbox. let me check its dashboard.

Comment: the transaction is waiting for reimbursement, is it about THB and default USD

Comment: In the javascript replied back, I noticed a payment was completed but the payee sandbank dash says 'waiting for process'. I then ask Paypal, and has no any answer yet.

Comment: If you mean the order completed but the payment is pending in the sandbox account, possible reasons are the sandbox account hasn't accepted a payment in that currency yet, or the payment is of type authorization and needs to be capture, or the email of the sandbox account hasn't been confirmed in the sandbox environment and developer notifications tab